# Does a closed form for this integral exist?

Tags: integration, closed-form, fractional-calculus

As part of a broader fractional integral calculation using the Riemann-Liouville operator, I encountered the following integral:

$$f(z,h,a) = \int_0^z\, \frac{h^{1-u}}{u-1}\cdot(z-u)^{a-1}\, du \qquad z \in \mathbb{C}. h,a \in \mathbb{R}$$

Could this integral be simplified further, e.g. by expressing it into a Hypergeometric function? I have tried Wolfram Math, but without any success. A complicating factor might be that when $z \in \mathbb{R}, z>1$, a pole will be induced in the integrand.

Comment: The case $=0$
 is given in terms of an incomplete gamma function $$\int_{0}^{z}\!{\frac {{h}^{1-u}}{u-1}}\,{\rm d}u=\Gamma(0,-\ln h)-\Gamma(0,-(z-1)\ln h) $$

Comment: If z is a complex number, then what is the path do you integrate from 0 to z?

Comment: @GEdgar The integral doesn't seem to converge for $a=0$. I actually forgot to add the constraint $a > 0$.

Comment: @MathFail Good question and I haven't given this much thought yet. I would already be happy with a solution valid for $z \in \mathbb{R} , z > 0$

Comment: Actually, this is really the case $a=1$, so that the $z-u$ factor is missing.$$\int_{0}^{z}\!{\frac {{h}^{1-u}}{u-1}}\,{\rm d}u=\Gamma(0,-\ln h)-\Gamma(0,(z-1)\ln h) $$

Comment: @GEdgar Ah, thanks for clarifying! Besides $a=1$, Wolfram Alpha also finds closed form expressions for the indefinite integral of higher integer values of $a$. These involve the $Ei$-function and sums of powers of $\ln(h)$ that are weighted by some polynomials.